# Should the present perfect form of the verb "continue" not be used in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs, present-perfect, present-simple

I have seen the following sentence in some article:

> Frankly, I think the point it makes is rather obvious, but to my surprise the publication was followed by a further flood of objections that - more surprisingly - **continues** to the present day.

The context is that the author stated a controversial point in his/her article in 1980, and the publisher had received many objections.

Regarding the adverb of time "to the present day" and the fact that the objections existed before the time of speaking, I wonder whether it is not better to use the **present perfect** form of the verb "continue", namely, "has continued" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Has continued" could be an acceptable alternative, but when saying "it has continued ***to** the present day*" it could sound like it *stopped* today - that the present day is when it continued *until*.

Saying "it continues" shows that it continues *on*, with no fixed end in view.

You could express the same by saying "it has continued *into* the present day".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think the simple present "continues" cannot semantically fit the context of the sentence due to presence of the proposition **to**; the proposition indicates (emphasizes) that there occurred an action in the past continuing to the time of speaking, which implies that the present perfect form of the verb must be used. In my opinion, we cannot *semantically* have sentences like "[subject] + [simple present] + ***to*** + [present day/now]." Am I right?

Comment: @Astralbee, pls reply to his comment.

Comment: @Later In other contexts you might be correct, but this is perfectly idiomatic. This is because 'the present day' is not a fixed time - it means the ongoing present.

Comment: @Astralbee Thanks. It seems that the author wanted to convert the compound phrase "has continued to the present day, and continues" into the briefer phrase "continues to the present day"; the former seems *more* grammatical while the latter is idiomatic. However, if I were the author, I would simply say "still continues", without "to the present day", in such a situation.